# Marklogic unable to return SQL response for super database using ODBC app server

Tags: odbc, marklogic

We are using MarkLogic 9.0-11. We have an ODBC app server that is attached to a SuperDatabase. This SuperDatabase has two sub database .

We are using admin user with admin privileges. When we log into the qconsole using admin user and select our superdatabase in dropdown, we have no problem running a SELECT SQL query and we will get a expected result something like below

```
Select count{*} from VehicleTable
Result  500
```

However if i use this SQL query from my ODBC app server in linux box(this ODBC app server is connected to superdatabase), something like below

```
[testuser@testdev001 ~]$ /usr/local/bin/isql -v MarkLogicSQL admin admintest123
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> Select count{*} from VehicleTable

+------------+
| count(*)   |
+------------+
| 0          |
+------------+
SQLRowCount returns 1
1 rows fetched
SQLRowCount returns -1
1 rows fetched
```

[Note, if we attach one of the sub database in our ODBC app server then we will get the result in SQL query from linux box]

Can anyone suggest why the same query is performing differently on the app server and qconsole. Any ideas?

Comment: There is likely something wrong with your configuration, but impossible to say what, based on data you provided.

Comment: Basically, I just want to check, when you configure ODBC app server in MarkLogic, then you had to mention details like root, port, modules, database. Now when we select database ex testdb (MarkLogic database), we will get the result from a Linux box, but when we mention superdatabase in ODBC app server configuration for ex "SuperTestdb", we will get only column name in Linux box, we are not getting data. But when we try to run the same sql query from query console over super database, we get the proper result.

Comment: This issue is resolved bu upgrading the MarkLogic version.